# What do I tell the user if the image they have to upload is very specific in height and width?

Tags: gui-design, mobile-application, style-guide

Am making an android app. I need to make the user be able to upload an image of a button that is pre-configured in size. So they would essentially be only changing the design.

My questions: 
**1. Should I limit the size and reject any image that is not of exact size in pixels (807x185) - OR - not reject anything but make the user at fault if the button looks bad/distorted?** (basically do I make the button and the image the same exact size or mold and fit the image into the 807x185 button frame no matter if it's smaller or bigger)
**2. How should I tell the user about this limitation?**

Comment: Trying to understand the functionality of the app. Why do the users upload buttons? Is it a customization feature or is it an app that helps in building another website/app?

Comment: It is purely a customization feature.

Comment: From personal experience, the more precise you'd want inputs to be, the more problems would occur. It might be better to provide in-app features to allow customization like color and font change. Or allow approximations via aspect ratios

Comment: That is a good suggestion! I might just stick with button color and text color changer instead of uploading a whole image. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don’t make them upload an image for a button.**

Users will more than likely not upload according to your requirements or lack the persistence/skill to craft to your specifications. This method is highly error prone with a significant risk of being a frustrating experience for the user.

The practice of using images for buttons creates unnecessary maintenance and load requirements on the system as well as being an accessibility problem for users with special needs.

Instead provide them with a html button and an interface to change the attributes of the button element. Consider implementing a small style editor with control over background, text and outline. In this way you control the format and flexibility with how the object can be integrated into the UI.

But, if this method is unacceptable then I would provide the user with a starter template and all the requirements/instructions up front. Absolutely run validations, just don’t expect many users to provide fixes for them unless they’re highly motivated.

Answer (score 2):

Provide Resize, Auto Crop, and Move Image features.

I would provide a preview window on the page that is a fixed size (it will be the exact size you need) and place the image over it, at its normal resolution.

- If the image resolution is larger than what you need, the image will overflow the preview window. Any part of that image that is within the preview window will appear ok, while any part outside the preview window will be ghosted out. The user can move the image if they want so that a different part of the large image is within the previw window.
- If the image resolution is smaller than the preview window, the image will appear ok within the boundary of the preview window.

You need a control to change the size of the image (keeping its aspect ratio) and controls to allow the user to move the image around, so that the user can ether:

- Make the whole image fit within the preview window using the resize control.
- Move the large image around (within some limits) so that a different portion of a large image will be cropped inside the preview window.

If the user does nothing with their large image you will auto-crop the portion of the image that is within the preview window when they click the CTA button.

Resize and Auto-Crop features allow the user the flexibility to upload any sized image with very little effort, and no error handling will be needed - whatever is within the preview window will be submitted.

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you for the experienced insight! But I have chosen another option of just avoiding having to upload an image in the first place, greatly simplifying the functionality at the cost of a little less customization.

Answer (score 1):

For this the ecosystem needs to be considered. If the user is required to upload only a particular size of the image, it is important to leave a way out for them to create that particular size. Resizing an image on a mobile device is not possible with the default applications. Therefore the application should be able to accept images of all types an Android phone may be able to produce. The right way to do it will be process the uploaded image and resize it at the back to suit the requirements. A crop feature is best-to-have to fix the aspect-ratio and select the intended part of the image.

The upload restrictions should always be mentioned outside the upload container so that the rules are visible with or without an image in the container.

Comment: Great advice about leaving the user a way out, I'll have that in mind the next time I have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Mention the required size. If possible allow the user to resize the image, crop it etc. Show errors for wrong sizes.